# I want to make this Javascript function more efficient?

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts

I have three pie charts being generated using Google Charts API. I want to compress this function further as there is a lot of duplication. Is there a loop I can make for it etc.

```
if (data) {
            var myVar = [];
            var myVar1 = [];
            var myVar2 = [];

            myVar.push(['Label', 'Value']);
            myVar1.push(['Label', 'Value']);
            myVar2.push(['Label', 'Value']);

            myVar.push(['Car Sales Today', data.salesToday, ]);
            myVar1.push(['Car Sales Yesterday', data.salesYesterday]);
            myVar2.push(['Car Sales Last Week', data.salesLastWeek]);

            var build1 = {
                package: 'PieChart',
                data: myVar,
                customTooltips: [
                    data.salesToday,
                ],
                container: 'today-sales-chart',
                options: {
                    width: 'auto',
                    height: 300,
                    chartArea: { width: '50%', height: '80%' },
                    yAxis: { textPosition: 'none' },
                    legend: { position: "bottom" },
                    tooltip: { isHtml: true },
                    colors: ['#e6dc39'],
                    pieSliceText: 'none'
                }
            };
            var build2 = {
                package: 'PieChart',
                data: myVar1,
                customTooltips: [
                    data.salesYesterday,
                ],
                container: 'yesterday-sales-chart',
                options: {
                    width: 'auto',
                    height: 300,
                    chartArea: { width: '50%', height: '80%' },
                    yAxis: { textPosition: 'none' },
                    legend: { position: "bottom" },
                    tooltip: { isHtml: true },
                    colors: ['#33bb18'],
                    pieSliceText: 'none'
                }
            };
            var build3 = {
                package: 'PieChart',
                data: myVar2,
                customTooltips: [
                    data.salesLastWeek
                ],
                container: 'lastweek-sales-chart',
                options: {
                    width: 'auto',
                    height: 300,
                    chartArea: { width: '50%', height: '80%' },
                    yAxis: { textPosition: 'none' },
                    legend: { position: "bottom" },
                    tooltip: { isHtml: true },
                    colors: ['#e06e29'],
                    pieSliceText: 'none'
                }
            };
            charts.push(build1, build2, build3);
            google.setOnLoadCallback.drawCharts(build1.container);
            google.setOnLoadCallback.drawCharts(build2.container);
            google.setOnLoadCallback.drawCharts(build3.container);
        }
```

I tried to do the following for example:

```
var myVar, myVar1, myVar2 = [];
```

but I get an error. Any help would be great.

Comment: "but I got an error" - what error did you get? It looks like most of your options are the same, you can remove duplication with `var options = { ... }` then using `options : options` for each chart.

Comment: You `build` variables are actually the same. Run it into a loop. You don't have to write it 3 times

Comment: You can create a function for creating your packages

Comment: It wasn't an error so much as the charts stopped rendering. 

I'm not sure how to write the function loop for creating the packages. I am new to writing functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took some time to optimize your code, but I didn't test it. make sure all the variable names are ok, and don't make a conflict on your code

```
if (data) {
    var allData = [{
            arr : [['Label', 'Value'], ['Car Sales Today', data.salesToday]],
            container : 'today-sales-chart',
            customTooltips: data.salesToday
        }
        ,{
            arr : [['Label', 'Value'], ['Car Sales Yesterday', data.salesYesterday]],
            container : 'yesterday-sales-chart',
            customTooltips: data.salesYesterday
        }
        ,{
            arr : [['Label', 'Value'], ['Car Sales Last Week', data.salesLastWeek]],
            container : 'lastweek-sales-chart',
            customTooltips: data.salesLastWeek
        }
    ];

    var options = {
        width: 'auto',
        height: 300,
        chartArea: { width: '50%', height: '80%' },
        yAxis: { textPosition: 'none' },
        legend: { position: "bottom" },
        tooltip: { isHtml: true },
        colors: ['#e6dc39'],
        pieSliceText: 'none'
    }

    var builds = [];
    for (var index in allData) {
        builds.push({
            package: 'PieChart',
            data: allData[index].arr,
            customTooltips: [ allData[index].customTooltips ],
            container: allData[index].container,
            options: options
        });
    }

    for(var index in builds) {
        charts.push(builds[index]);
        google.setOnLoadCallback.drawCharts(builds[index].container);
    }
}
```

**Update**

to add the possibility to change the color, in this case you don't need to use options as an independent variable :

```
    var builds = [];
    for (var index in allData) {
        builds.push({
            package: 'PieChart',
            data: allData[index].arr,
            customTooltips: [ allData[index].customTooltips ],
            container: allData[index].container,
            options: {
                width: 'auto',
                height: 300,
                chartArea: { width: '50%', height: '80%' },
                yAxis: { textPosition: 'none' },
                legend: { position: "bottom" },
                tooltip: { isHtml: true },
                colors: allData[index].color, // <--- you set the color here
                pieSliceText: 'none'
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: This looks great, pretty much what I was hoping to achieve. Thanks very much. One last question, if I wanted to apply a different color to each pie chart, eg the Car Sales Today chart is yellow, Yesterday is green etc how would I do this? Create an array of the colors?

Comment: you just need to do the same things as I did for `customTooltips: data.salesToday`

Comment: When I add  `container : 'today-sales-chart',  customTooltips: data.salesToday, colors: ['yellow']` my charts stop rendering. Is this because the colors of the chart are tied to the options object(?)?

Comment: Thanks very much again, so with the `colors: allData[index].color` I should now add in a `color: 'yellow'` for eg below `customTooltips: data.salesToday`? And do this for each arr: object to generate the different colour charts?

Comment: yes, but you need to make sure you set the right data type, in your example I noticed that you give an array to the attribute color `colors: ['#e6dc39']` , so I suggest you to put the color like this : `color : ['#e6dc39']`   below customTooltips , and on the build you just need to add this : `colors: allData[index].color`